# Get the amount of consecutive values from the end of the table

Tags: php, mysql, count, row

I need help with this one, i have no idea how to make it.

Here is my data in MySql

```
----------------------
|  id  |     color   |
----------------------
|  1   |     green   |
|  2   |     red     |
|  3   |     red     |
|  4   |     black   |
|  5   |     red     |
|  6   |     black   |
|  7   |     black   |
----------------------
```

How to count the last data in color ? but not in all rows, I want to count only how much time is last data one after another. In this case result shuld be:

**black is 2 times in a row**

or

```
----------------------
|  id  |     color   |
----------------------
|  1   |     green   |
|  2   |     red     |
|  3   |     red     |
|  4   |     black   |
|  5   |     red     |
|  6   |     black   |
|  7   |     black   |
|  9   |     green   |
| 10   |     red     |
| 11   |     red     |
| 12   |     red     |
----------------------
```

and here will be:

**red is 3 times in a row**

Comment: When you say `last` you mean ordered by `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a valid case for User Defined Variables. This solution will work regardless of whether the `ID` column has consecutive values or not:

```
select max(amount) amount from (
    select color,
        @found := if(@found, true, @prev_color != color),
        @prev_color := color,
        @amount := @amount + (not @found) amount
    from table, (
        select @prev_color := (select color from table order by id desc limit 1),
        @found := false,
        @amount := 0) init
    order by id desc
) s
```

See it working [here](http://sqlize.com/3uffEBRCA8).

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the query. This should do the trick

```
 SELECT count(`color`) FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `color` ORDER BY `id` DESC Limit 0,1
```

Comment: This has the same issue as Jacob's (actually, it is the same query). You need to count only the last 3 and you're counting all. You need to process from bottom to top and stop counting when you reach a different value from the last one.

Answer (score 0):

do you finish it in mysql or  php?

i don't konw mysql;
but php you can do like this:

fetch all the result through the sql "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC ":

```
$count=0;$currentcolor='';

$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$currentcolor=$row['color'];

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   if($row['color']==$currentcolor){
       $count++;
   }else{
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result you are looking for

```
SELECT COUNT(color) FROM table GROUP BY color ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Actually it won't. It will return 6 for the second set of data in the OP's question because you're counting all the `red` instead of just the last `3`.